# How to redirect to another page when a network-related or instance-specific error in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I always get the error :

```
 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Now, I want to redirect my project to one page that show the message "We will back soon" or something else beside that error message that occurred.

Could anyone can tell me how can I do this in my asp.net mvc 2.0 project?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you currently handling errors in your application (if you are handling errors at all)?

Comment: I'm not yet do any thing that handle the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Application_Error` event in your `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    var sqlException = exception as SqlException;
    // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603.aspx 
    // for a full list of error numbers that you might be interested in
    if (sqlException != null && sqlException.Number == 2)
    {
        // it was a SqlException with error number = 2 meaning that this
        // is the exception that you wanted to handle => we redirect to some page
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("~/Offline.htm");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clear the Server error before redirecting. I have updated my answer. See if this works for you.

Comment: Is the Application_Error method being hit when you put a breakpoint? If yes, what is the exception being caught? Is it a SqlException? There must be something that you are missing because this code worked fine for me when I tested it.

Comment: Application_Error method being hit but SqlExeption is null.

Comment: What is the exception then (`exception` variable)?

Comment: `exception = {"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Ib.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."}`

Comment: Dude, this exception has absolutely nothing to do with a SqlException. You have some other problem. Is there an InnerException associated to it?

Comment: If the SQL Server is down, your client code will catch a SqlException.

Comment: It works for me if I put `Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();`